# how can I connect two expressions using AND operator?

Tags: regex

First expression - there must be minimum 1 letter:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{1,}$
```

Second expression - there can be only chars from list: `a-zA-Z0-9.&@-+_!$%(space)` , minimum 1 and maximum 11:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9.&@\-+_!$% ]{1,11}$
```

I would like to connect those two expressions using AND operator.
But the code below doesn't work:

```
^(?=[a-zA-Z]{1,})(?=[a-zA-Z0-9.&@\-+_!$% ]{1,11})$
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by AND? Should the expression satisfy *both* expressions at the same time? Could you give us more details about the problem are trying to solve?

Comment: Your first expression does not mean what you think; rather, it means "consists *solely* of one or more letters".

Comment: It can be for example: 67@g83 - there must be always minimum one letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try that:

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z]+)[a-zA-Z0-9.&@\-+_!$% ]{1,11}$
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/8UT9A6/2)

1. ^ asserts position at start of a line
2. Positive Lookahead (?=.*[a-zA-Z]+)
3. Match a single character present in the list below `[a-zA-Z0-9.&@\-+_!$% ]{1,11}`
4. {1,11} Quantifier — Matches between 1 and 11 times(greedy)
5. $ asserts position at the end of a line